# Django-oscar : deleting a voucher don't delete the associated "ConditionalOffer"

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm facing a problem with Django-Oscar wile trying to play with offers and vouchers. When I delete a voucher the related entity ConditionalOffer is not deleted and remain in database.

So when I try to add another voucher with the same code as the one I just deleted I get a beautiful IntegrityError `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "offer_conditionaloffer_name_key"`

I'm using django-oscar (2.0.1) with PostgreSQL (11) and psycopg2 (2.8.3).

Here a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8pG8.png) of the error and another of the [ConditionalOffer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4AgZ.png) with entries (10off and 20off) remaining there.

Is that normal behaviour or a bug? If it's normal how can I do to create a voucher with the same code as an old one already deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal (if somewhat undesirable) behaviour - Oscar doesn't clean up offers that were created with a voucher. The reason for this is that as far as the models are concerned, an offer can be associated with any number of vouchers - so it doesn't assume that when a voucher is deleted the offer is no longer needed.

There is probably an argument that if an offer is created for a voucher through the dashboard, and shares the same name, then it should be deleted when the voucher is - but this isn't currently implemented.

For now you will need to delete the orphaned offer either from the Django admin, or from the shell.

Comment: when you say "an offer can be associated with any number of vouchers" you mean through VoucherSets ? Also there is a table called ```voucher_voucher_offers``` which contains links between vouchers and offers so normally an offer (created for a voucher) without an entry in this table should be deleted. It makes sense ?

Comment: No, I mean that [one voucher can have multiple offers assigned to it](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/voucher/abstract_models.py#L128-L130). Voucher sets are a separate thing and not related to the issue you have. There is a valid argument for saying offers attached to a voucher should be deleted - I'm just saying that Oscar doesn't currently do this.